# extracting data after the certain string till the new line in python

Tags: python

I have below lines in the email.

```
data=
'''
ABC something random: Adele Vance <AdeleV@contoso.OnMicrosoft.com>
To: Megan Bowen <MeganB@contoso.OnMicrosoft.com>
XYZ something random: Press conference
'''
```

I want to extract everything after "To:" till the next line.
Currently I am doing the following.

```
start=data.find("To:") #Index where To starts
end=data.find("\n") #Index of a new line
expected_string=data[start:end].strip()
```

But it's not working as expected.
How can I extract the data after"To" till the new line?
i.e

`To: Megan Bowen <MeganB@contoso.OnMicrosoft.com>`

Answer (score 2):

So basically `.find()` returns the starting index of the substring if it is present in the string.

So in this case
`start=data.find("To:")`

will return the starting index. Now problem arises in `end=data.find("\n") #Index of a new line` this part as this will return the index of first `\n` which is the end of first line. So we have to specify the starting point in `find`. We can do that as follows.

```py
data= '''
ABC something random: Adele Vance <AdeleV@contoso.OnMicrosoft.com>
To: Megan Bowen <MeganB@contoso.OnMicrosoft.com>
XYZ something random: Press conference
'''

start_index = data.find('To:')
end_index = data.find('\n',start_index)
start_string = data[start_index:end_index]

print(start_string)
```

Here if you look, I added the `start_index` when finding `\n` which will find the backslash n in the line where "To:" is present.

Answer (score 2):

`end=data.find("\n")` is going to find the index of the *first* newline in `data`.

What you want might be to first split data by the `\n` delimiter, and then search through each row until you find the entry/entries you want, e.g.:

```
rows = data.split('\n')
for row in rows:
    if row.find('To:') == 0: # row begins with 'To:'
        pass # do something with it
```

A terser way of filtering out all rows that match your criterion could be the following expression:

```
[row for row in data.split('\n') if row.find('To:') == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "\n" since there is a \n right before "TO:"

i.e.technically this is what python sees:

```
'ABC something random: Adele Vance <AdeleV@contoso.OnMicrosoft.com>\nTo: Megan Bowen <MeganB@contoso.OnMicrosoft.com>\nXYZ something random: Press conference\n'
```

so instead you need to use the first part of the next line:

```
start=data.find("To:") #Index where To starts
end=data.find("XYZ") #Index of a new line
expected_string=data[start:end].strip()
```

You should get the following output:

```
'To: Megan Bowen <MeganB@contoso.OnMicrosoft.com>'
```